# How do I convert this excel formula to a power BI custom column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I  have a long if formula in excel and need to convert it to an if formula in Power BI. Any ideas?

Excel Formula:
`=IF(AND(OR(LEFT(X2,3)="866", LEFT(X2,3)="086"), V2="", X2<>""), "Secondary Applied",IF(AND(OR(E2="ZD", E2="ZS"), V2="", X2="<>"),"Secondary Applied", IF(AND(X2="",OR(E2="ZD", E2="ZS")),"Secondary Unapplied",IF(AND(LEFT(X2,3)<>"866",LEFT(X2,3)<>"086",OR(E2<>"ZD", E2<>"ZS",Z2="Applied"),AA2="Applied"),"Applied","Unapplied"))))`

I tried rewriting it as :

```
NewColumn = IF (
(Text.Start([X2], 3) = "866" || Text.Start([X2], 3) = "086")
    && [V2] = ""
    && [X2] <> "",
"Secondary Applied",
IF (
    ([E2] = "ZD" || [E2] = "ZS")
        && [V2] = ""
        && [X2] <> "",
    "Secondary Applied",
    IF (
        [X2] = "" && ([E2] = "ZD" || [E2] = "ZS"),
        "Secondary Unapplied",
        IF (
            Text.Start([X2], 3) <> "866"
                && Text.Start([X2], 3) <> "086"
                && ([E2] <> "ZD" || [E2] <> "ZS" || [Z2] = "Applied")
                && [AA2] = "Applied",
            "Applied",
            "Unapplied"
        )
    )
)
```

)

Obviously, I changed it to the column names but it still didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here DAX formula:

```
Column = SWITCH(TRUE(),
OR(LEFT([X2],3)="866", LEFT([X2],3)="086") && [V2]=BLANK() && [X2] <>BLANK(),"Secondary Applied",
OR([E2]="ZD", [E2]="ZS") && [V2]=BLANK() && [X2]="<>","Secondary Applied", 
AND([X2]=BLANK(),OR([E2]="ZD", [E2]="ZS")),"Secondary Unapplied",
LEFT([X2],3)<>"866" && LEFT([X2],3)<>"086" && ([E2]<>"ZD" || [E2]<>"ZS" || [Z2]="Applied") && [AA2]="Applied","Applied","Unapplied")
```

> Note: Above is create new column in Powerbi with DAX formula, not M code in PowerQuery.

[image]